# How to get a element(at head) form ConcurrentLinkedQueue in java without removing the element

Tags: java, java-8

How to get an element(at head) from ConcurrentLinkedQueue in java without removing the element

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You just call [`element()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#element()), from the `Queue` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueueObject.peek()
```